# Error al insertar datos desde php

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una pequeña base de datos en la cual quiero ingresar la fecha y hora actual del sistema dependiendo de la zona horaria, no se de que tipo deben ser exactamente en la base de datos para que se ingresen.

este es mi código para insertar los datos:

```
<?php

    require 'conexion.php';

    $username = ('usuario1');
    $fecha = date('d-m-Y');
    $hora = date('H:i:s');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO registro (usuario, fecha, hora) VALUES ('$usuario', '$fecha', '$hora')";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

?>
```

espero que alguien pueda ayudarme a corregir el error.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? Y, ¿por qué intentas guardar fecha y hora por separado cuando **las puedes guardar juntas en una columna del tipo `DATETIME`**?

Comment: no registra los datos en la base, y me pidieron por separado fecha y hora al momento del registro, aunque tendré que dejarlo en uno solo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freshman, revisa tu código. Te dejo el código que ya lo he probado.

**1 - Conexion**

```
<?php
$dbname ="db_prueba";
$usuario = "root";
$password = "";

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","",$dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
// Change database to "mi_base_de_datos"
mysqli_select_db($con,$dbname);
echo 'conexion exitosa';
?>
```

**2 - Inserción de datos**

```
<?php
    require 'conexion.php';

    $username = ('usuario1');
    $fecha = date('Y-m-d');
    $hora = date('H:i:s');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO registro (usuario, fecha, hora) VALUES ('$username', '$fecha', '$hora')";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**3 - Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Comment: Cambia $usuario por $username

Comment: agradezco tu ayuda, me ha sido muy útil hasta ahora

Comment: ya hice el arreglo del código con estos cambios y me funciono muy bien, pero ahora estoy buscando como hacer para que al momento de dar click en una etiqueta `<a>` en la misma página, inserte los datos.

Comment: así lo estoy tratando de implementar:
`<?php
 
 require 'conexion.php';
 
 if (isset($_POST['registrar'])) {
  
  $username = ('usuario1');
  $fecha = date('Y-m-d');
  $hora = date('H:i:s');
  
  $sql = "INSERT INTO registro (usuario, fecha, hora) VALUES ('$username', '$fecha', '$hora')";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  mysqli_close($con);
  
 }
 
?>`

la etiqueta que hace referencia:
`<div class="row">
            <a name="registrar" href="../index.php" class="btn btn-primary" style="border:none">< Volver</a>
</div>`